# Android Studio Emulator poop out instead of tabbed pinned in studio

Tags: java, android-studio

whenever I run my app my emulator poops out instead of getting pinned inside Android Studio is there a fix for this?

My Android Studio: [image]

What I want: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have this option in Android Studio's preferences:

[image]